# Map enumareted properties to array by Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Given is an class with indexed properties

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Bar1 { get; set; } = 17;
        public int Bar2 { get; set; } = 42;
        public int Bar3 { get; set; } = 99;
        ... 
                   Bar<n>
    }
```

result is

List of int contain 17,42,99 ...

How to configure mapper that I can consume Automapper like this

```
List<int> bars = mapper.Map<List<int>>(foo);
```

Comment: First of all I don't think that counts as "indexed properties", but only something for human readability. However with a combination of a custom value resolver and reflection you should be able to get this done with automapper.

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with [Reflection](https://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection)

```
List<int> bars = new List<int>(foo.GetType()
                                  .GetProperties()
                                  .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                                  .Select(x => (int)x.GetValue(foo)));
```

Or if you also need the property names to sort or filter them in some way

```
 Dictionary<string, int> bars = foo.GetType()
                                   .GetProperties()
                                   .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Name,  x => (int)x.GetValue(foo));
```

Comment: This misses the automapper configuration that was asked for. Also this just puts all properties of type `int` in a list instead of using the "indexed" name convention OP mentioned, though that might not be needed since it might be implied that the class only contains those indexed properties

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Innat3 on this but his answer misses few points. Here:

```
        var bars = foo.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Bar"))
            .Select(x => (int)x.GetValue(foo))
            .ToList();
```

And of course it doesn't involves Automapper as well as your indexed properties. I didn't rely on them cuz I don't know how exactly you implemented those.

Comment: OrderBy is missing :)